# Download Singularity images for local builds

Tags: download, singularity-container

I have a system that has no connection to the internet but does have local mirrors of the OS package manager repos, PyPI, Conda, etc. I'd like to build Singularity images on this system. It looks like the [`localimage` bootstrap agent](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.3/user-guide/appendix.html#build-localimage) was designed specifically for this use case, but how would I download the base image from which to build my images? From an internet-connected machine, can I download an "official" base image from SyLabs, Singularity Hub, or somewhere else in my browser without installing Singularity?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would probably be to use singularity to build just the base image on the internet connected computer. For example, if you would normally bootstrap off `ubuntu:latest` from Docker hub:

```
sudo singularity build ubuntu_latest.sif docker://ubuntu:latest
```

Then copy it to the offline server and use that with `Bootstrap: localimage`.